# Why there is still python process after I shut down a running python program in MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, process

After I quit a running python program or notebook by *Control + Z*, there is still one or two python process background and occupy such high CPU resources.

Even after I run *killall python* or *pkill python*, It's still here and make my fans running fast;
[python process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Zwq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-terminal): If we leave edge cases to one side, the difference is simple. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> aborts the application almost immediately while <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shunts it into the background, suspended.

Therefore, you did not quit it, just suspended it. Use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for quiting/terminating.